# Restrict AWS EC2 outbound traffic with a security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I want to restrict outbound traffic for my EC2 instance, to only allow outbound connections to AWS services such as ECR, EFS. However these services dont have static ip addresses, so I cant add this to the security groups. Is there a common way to do this which I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to run your instances in a private subnet and use a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to provide access to AWS services.

But before taking that step, what is the threat that you're attempting to overcome?

Comment: To ensure no outbound connections can be made to unapproved destinations.

Comment: That's not a threat, it's a proposed solution to a threat. A threat would be "we're running containers created by a third party, and are concerned that they will use our AWS credentials." Which would probably have a different solution from "we're running containers created by a third party, and are concerned that they will be used to mine bitcoin."

Answer (score 1):

You don't do that with `Security Groups`. You do that with `IAM role`.

Comment: I have an IAM role already set up to access ECR and this works fine. However when I remove the all outbound traffic rule in the security group I am unable to access ECR. Also removing all outbound traffic also means I can no longer access IAM. So I would like to add the ECR endpoint and IAM endpoint as outbound rules however they dont have static ip's

Comment: You cannot use SG to restrict access to AWS services. You do that with IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very very old question, stumbled across this while trying to figure this out myself. By default AWS security groups allow all outbound traffic. Outbound traffic can be blocked by

- Removing the default allow all outbound traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 rule
- Add a rule to a specific IP address and port

Answer (score 0):

There are services exposing their IPs like EFS, FSx, RDS, etc in which case the IP would at least appear into your "Network Interfaces" on the EC2 page so that you can apply your Security Group rule.

In some cases, such as EFS, it even asks you to apply a SG during the creation. ECS has EC2 instances deployed if it isn't using Fargate. ECR is restricted at app layer, but [you can further restrict/allow IPs with a policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html).

So, there's always a way to know the IPs to allow/restrict or a way to do it and, if the service has no IP, then yes, you'll not be able to add it to a Security Group, but an attacker won't be able to target it too.

For what concern those AWS services your instance *must* contact in order to work, they are allowed by default, [see the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html):

> Amazon security groups and network ACLs do not filter traffic destined to and from the following Amazon services:
>
> - Amazon Domain Name Services (DNS)
> - Amazon Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)
> - Amazon EC2 instance metadata
> - Amazon Windows license activation
> - Amazon Time Sync Service
> - Reserved IP address of the default VPC router

So, there are no chance you can (accidentally) restrict access to AWS internal services (such IAM).